# Getting the git differences between a locally changed file and a different branch

Tags: git

I'm made some modifications to a local file, but haven't committed it yet.  I want to do a git diff of this current version with the one from a different branch, but when I do:

```
git diff master otherbranch myfile.txt
```

it looks like it's showing the difference between the last commit of myfile.txt in the current branch and the current version, not the difference with the other branch and the current version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're very close!

> ```
> git diff master otherbranch myfile.txt
> ```

This "means" the same thing as `git diff master otherbranch -- myfile.txt`, which, as we see in [the `git diff` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html), has the general form:

> ```
> git diff <commit> <commit> -- <path>
> ```
>
> This is to view the changes between two arbitrary <commit>.

What you *want* is just above that:

> This form is to view the changes you have in your working tree relative to the named <commit>. You can use HEAD to compare it with the latest commit, or a branch name to compare with the tip of a different branch.

and looking up just one line further in the manual page you will see:

> *git diff* [--options] <commit> [--] [<path>...]

which would be:

```
git diff otherbranch -- myfile.txt
```

The reason to use the `--` is in case you need to diff a file named, e.g., `--name-only` or `-w` or some such.  It's a good idea to get into the habit of just always using it, not that it really matters for `git diff`, but someday if you accidentally create a file named `-rf`,<sup>1</sup> and run `git rm -- -rf`, you will realize that it's a very good habit. :-)

It's a good idea to read and study the manual page, because there are a *lot* of forms of `git diff`—name no commits, name 1 commit, or name 2 commits; use or omit `--staged`—all of which diff different things.  It took me about a year to get to the point of knowing which one to use without having to double check the manual.

---

<sup>1</sup>Really, this sometimes happens, especially if a co-worker decides to prank you and runs `: > ./-rf`.  Another way to deal with it is to use `./-rf`, just like the prank, since `./-rf` does not start with `-`.  But it's just a good habit.